# kubernetes nginx ingress controller aws application load balancer 404 error

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

But it show 404 page not found when i hit it in browser. Please tell me where the issue

nginx-deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

nginx-service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx
    svc: test-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
```

```text
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.100.21.122    <pending>     80:30237/TCP,443:30080/TCP   14h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.100.248.124   <none>        443/TCP                      14h
kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      14h
nginx-service                        ClusterIP      10.107.238.84    <none>        8080/TCP                     14h
```

nginx-ingress.yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ingress-lb-2018265909.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: I think that the External Ip of the LoadBalancer service being Pending may be your problem. Can you check logs to see if you reach the Nginx Controller Pod at least or not?

Comment: you dont have an ingress class on your ingress manifest. And as mentioned by AndD,  your controllers external IP is pending.

Comment: You don't have external IP, so how did you try to hit this page from the browser? Please check the logs and paste them to the question.

Comment: you put a bounty, but you havent adressed any comment about your the external loadbalancer being in pending state. In fact what you show here has nothing to do with your problem, since you are trying to use the ingress controller, while you have actually issues deploying it properly. You need to go back and review how you have set up your ingress controller in the first place. If you want help, you also should include that information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone I get my answer . I need to setup metalLB to setup ingress in bare metal server

Answer (score 0):

External Ip of the LoadBalancer service being Pending may be your problem.  check logs to see if you reach the Nginx Controller Pod[.](https://besttanklessguide.com/)